# Calling C++ constructor issue

Tags: c++, constructor

I am seriously misunderstanding c++ constructors. In the code shown below, I am trying to inialize aVar in MyClass1. The code generates the following errors (also shown in the code):

(1) "aVar2" has already been declared in the current scope
(2)  reference variable "var" requires an initializer

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

```
class Myclass1
{
public:
    Myclass1(int * var1);
    Myclass1(void);

private:
    int * aVar;
};

class Myclass2
{
public:
    Myclass2(int * var2);

private:
    Myclass1 myclass1;

};

class Myclass3
{
public:
    Myclass3(void);

private:
    Myclass2 myclass2;
    int var;
};

Myclass1::Myclass1(int * aVar1)
{

    aVar = aVar1;
}

Myclass2::Myclass2(int * aVar2)
{
   //ERROR: "aVar2" has already been declared in the current scope  
    Myclass1(aVar2);
}

Myclass3::Myclass3(void)
{
    var = 2;

    //ERROR: reference variable "var" requires an initializer
    Myclass2(&var);
}

int main(void)
{

    Myclass3 myFinalClass;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have some basic errors. It will be good to back to a text book or an online tutorial on classe.

Comment: Fixed version: http://goo.gl/xOz5dY Maybe you understand it from my comments... I don't have time for a full answer atm.

Answer (score 1):

```
Myclass1(aVar2);
```

isn't right, since the member variable name is `myclass1` and also you've to assign to it like this: `myclass1 = aVar2`. Here the compiler thinks that you're just trying to create a new `Myclass1` object with the same name as the parameter. Here's what you need:

```
Myclass2::Myclass2(int * aVar2) : myclass1(aVar2) { }

Myclass3::Myclass3() : myclass2(&var) { }
```

Know that initializer lists are always better than initializing the members in the constructor body; see [the C++ FAQ on this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists). Apart from giving a uniform syntax, it *may be* faster too. So your `Myclass1` constructor would be better in this form:

```
Myclass1::Myclass1(int * aVar1) : aVar(aVar1) { }
```

Comment: Fantastic! In the actual program, I am not initializing the class with a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

`Myclass1(aVar2)` is not a constructor call, it is a definition of the aVar2 object.